# Installing MySQL 5.1 & PHP 5.2 on RHEL5.3

Tags: redhat, rhel5, php5, mysql5

I would quite like to be running the latest production releases of PHP and MySQL on my production RHEL5.3 server.

PHP so that I can use Zend Framework 1.9 which only supports PHP 5.2.4 or later.
MySQL because they claim 5.1 is faster.

I am a little concerned about installing from RPM's because of breaking dependencies and having to manually keep things up-to-date afterwards.

After a bit of research, I found the [Remi Repository](http://blog.famillecollet.com/).

If I add this to my list of repositories, yum update will be able to upgrade PHP and MySQL.

This sounds too good to be true - so are there any pitfalls or problems that I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd now recommend IUS Community Project at http://iuscommunity.org/ instead of Remi Repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why "this sounds too good to be true".

Considerinh PHP 5.2 was released quite a few years ago, the problem is that Redhat/CentOS are really **late** about that *(yeah, I know, "stable" and all that, which means not updating anything except for security reasons)*

Happily, some people stepped up, and did the job that had to be done : create the RPM packages that so many of us needed ;-)

Only thing there might be : it won't be "offcial" packages ; so maybe not OK with the policy of your system admins ?

Still, if in doubt : before using those on your production server, you should try them on a test server *(if you don't have one, a Virtual Machine will do just fine)*, just to be sure -- and, also, to check that your application works fine on 5.2

On the other hand, you might want to try compiling PHP by yourself : it is definitly not that hard, and it's a good thing to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you install php and mysql from Remi's repository, yum will be able to keep your packages up-to-date.